# How to change the subplot width/height ratio using matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

If the following code is run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
a=[[1,2,3],[4,4,4]]
gridspec.GridSpec(2,1)
plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (0,0), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.imshow(a)
plt.savefig('fig.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

I got the picture below. How to set the width/height ratio of subplot as 1:2, so it can be longer?

[image]

Basically, how to do this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default matplotlib shows images with a 1:1 aspect ratio, i.e. each pixel is as wide as it is high. Aspect is defined as height/width. You can set `aspect=2` to get an image with pixels twice as heigh as wide.

```
plt.imshow(a, aspect=2)
```

Comment: thank you very much. So it is nothing to do with `gridspec` and `figsize`?

Comment: Independent of the subplots aspect you can of course use a gridspec to position the subplot or change the figure size. For the simple problem from the question there seems to be no relation between aspect and gridspec or figsize. (Apart from the fact that it makes sense to use a figure size which somehow lets the subplot of the desired aspect look good inside the canvas.)